# Convert 'yyyy-mm-dd' string to 3-tuple datetime objects in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime

I am trying to convert a list of 'yyyy-mm-dd' strings into a list of datetime objects using strptime.

```
    dates = ['2014-01-01', '2014-03-07']
    datetime_objects = [datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d') for date in dates]
```

Printing datetime_objects give me:

```
    [datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2014, 3, 7, 0, 0)]
```

I need 3-tuple objects instead and don't need hours and minutes. How can I get this?

```
    [datetime.datetime(2011, 2, 21), datetime.datetime(2011, 9, 5)].
```

I am using Python 2.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want `datetime` objects; you want `date` objects, which are provided by the `date` method:

```
from datetime import datetime

dates = ['2014-01-01', '2014-03-07']
date_objects = [datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
                     for date in dates]
```

Answer (score 0):

Each datetime object has the .date() option:

```
In [167]: date_tuple = []

In [168]: for date in dates:
    x = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d')
    date_tuple.append((x.date()))    .....:     

In [169]: date_tuple Out[169]: [datetime.date(2014, 1, 1), datetime.date(2014, 3, 7)]
```